# Как вытащить url

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет, так как не силен в регулярках, обращаюсь к вам. Помогите пожалуйста, вытащить значение file и image

```
Куча HTML кода

<embed src="http://www.site.com/mp3/bia2player.swf" width="635" height="380" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="&amp;file=http://static.site.com/mp3/Tanbalim-Tanbe10_ft_Justina(www.site.com).mp3&amp;height=380&amp;image=http://static.site.com/images/mp3/player/cover_tanbalim_large.jpg&amp;width=635&amp;frontcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;backcolor=0x000000&amp;lightcolor=0x00CCCC&amp;showeq=true&amp;autostart=true&amp;repeat=true">
Куча HTML кода
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?

$str = '<embed src="http://www.site.com/mp3/bia2player.swf" width="635" height="380" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="&amp;file=http://static.site.com/mp3/Tanbalim-Tanbe10_ft_Justina(www.site.com).mp3&amp;height=380&amp;image=http://static.site.com/images/mp3/player/cover_tanbalim_large.jpg&amp;width=635&amp;frontcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;backcolor=0x000000&amp;lightcolor=0x00CCCC&amp;showeq=true&amp;autostart=true&amp;repeat=true">';

preg_match("/file=([-a-zA-Z:;\/\.\d_()]*)/",$str,$file);
preg_match("/image=([-a-zA-Z:;\/\.\d_()]*)/",$str,$image);

echo $file[1]."<br>";
echo $image[1]."<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Это больше к этому конкретному случаю. В идеале, нужно знать какие символы вообще возможны в значениях file и image. :-)

P.S. Обожаю регулярочки. :-)

Comment: Регулярки я Вам буду приносить вместо шоколадок :)